# Understanding HBase scan metrics

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to understand the meaning of few of the metrics from HBase ScanMetrics

```
Scan metrics: {count of regions: 1, remote rpc calls: 15, remote rpc retries: 0, Sum of Milli seconds between nexts: 8380}
```

I have set client side caching of rows to 10000 so that each call to next will give me those many rows. The scan query i am doing fetched total of 13000 rows. Following lists my understanding and questions regarding scan metrics output

---

```
count of regions: 1
All rows were found in 1 region. Correct me if i am wrong.
```

---

```
remote rpc calls: 15

Don't understand why this is 15. What all does this include
other than actual calls to the region server to fetch rows.
```

---

```
Sum of Milli seconds between nexts: 8380

Does this include time taken for any intermediate
processing between successive calls to next?
```

---